# How to use Socket.select

Tags: sockets, select, sml

How do I go about using `Socket.select` in Standard ML?

According to the [docs](http://sml-family.org/Basis/socket.html#SIG:SOCKET.select:VAL), I'm supposed to pass it three lists of sockets and a timeout `option`, and the function returns when any of the sockets are ready to do something (and I assume, but don't know for sure that the sockets in the out list are *only* the ones that need attention). However,

1. The input seems to be neither a tuple, nor four arguments. How do I go about constructing an appropriate input structure?
2. `select` takes and returns lists of `sock_desc`, and there doesn't seem to be a way of getting a `socket` back from its `sock_desc`. There also doesn't seem to be a way of constructing an efficient map, since it doesn't seem to be possible to order two `sock_desc`s, merely compare them for equality. Once I've got the return value from `select`, how do I do anything useful with the returned sockets, such as write responses out, or call `accept` on them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The input argument is a record with four fields, so your code should look something like this:

```ml
Socket.select {
  rds = readSocketDescs,
  wrs = writeSocketDescs,
  exs = exnSocketDescs,
  timeout = SOME (Time.fromSeconds 10)
}
```

2. Yeah, not sure, probably you need to keep a mapping yourself using lists. Not very efficient, but I can't see what else you can do.

````ml
(**
 * Produces a list of all the pairs in `listPair`, whose keys are present
 * in `whiteList`. Example:
 *
 * ```sml
 * - filterListPair op= [(1,"a"), (2,"b"), (3,"c")] [2,3];
 * val it = [(2,"b"),(3,"c")] : (int * string) list
 * ```
 *)
fun filterListPair eq listPair whiteList =
  let
    fun recur listPair whiteList result =
      case (listPair, whiteList) of
        ([], _) => result
      | (_, []) => result
      | ((x, y) :: xs, k :: ks) =>
          if eq (x, k)
          then recur xs ks ((x, y) :: result)
          else recur xs whiteList result
  in
    List.rev (recur listPair whiteList [])
  end

val sockets = [ (* what have you *) ]
val descsToSockets = List.map (fn s => (Socket.sockDesc s, s)) sockets
val { rds, wrs, exs } = Socket.select {
  rds = readSocketDescs,
  wrs = writeSocketDescs,
  exs = exnSocketDescs,
  timeout = SOME (Time.fromSeconds 10)
}

(*
 * The contract of Socket.select ensures that the order in input lists
 * is preserved in the output lists, so we can use `filterListPair`.
 *)
val selectedReadSockets =
  filterListPair Socket.sameDesc descsToSockets rds
````